# Регулярное выражение для проверки корректности ввода текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Мне нужно регулярное выражение для проверки ввода текста. Пользователь может ввести слово (слова) не начинающиеся с пробела, а также цифр и различных символов. Длина выражения должна быть более 4 букв.

Делаю так:

```
^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁ/\w]{4,}
```

Например, вводится фраза:

```
тест текст
```

Срабатывает корректно.
Но если ввести:

```
это тест
```

Уже не сработает, т.к. естественно данная регулярка проверяет длину первого слова (`это`), а нужно чтобы длина проверялось фразы целиком

Answer (score 0):

Если важно с чего начинается строка, но пробелы на конце допустимы и входят в длину строки, то можно использовать такое выражение:  `^[\w].{3,}`

Если хвостовые пробелы не входят в допустимую длину, то попробуйте такое выражение: `^[\w].{2,}\w`

Comment: На всякий случай: начало последовательности символов в Ruby-регулярках это `\A`, а конец это `\z` (да, разный регистр `\Z` нестрогий). А `^` и `$` это для отдельных строк, разделяемых newline-сочетаниями.